# Use AWS authentication for Amazon Open Search Service (AOSS)

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

We have an AOSS cluster and I'd like to use regular AWS console authentication to authenticate users.  I've reviewed (and followed much of) the following:

- [Configuring Amazon Cognito authentication for OpenSearch Dashboards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/cognito-auth.html)
- [How to enable secure access to Kibana using AWS Single Sign-On](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-enable-secure-access-to-kibana-using-aws-single-sign-on/)
- [Configure SAML single sign-on for Kibana with AD FS on Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/configure-saml-single-sign-on-for-kibana-with-ad-fs-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service/)

They all seem to use third-party SAML/AD-like services or to create/manage users separately from the AWS users/groups we've already set up.

Is there a way to, in essence, use AWS console authentication for AOSS access?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ac.html

Creating policies should work as usual.